# Why is uri path not working with File?

Tags: android, file, uri

Hi I am picking any file in android using following intent :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I am getting Uri for picked file & also I am getting file path by calling `uri.getPath()` method. After getting path I am creating file object using `file = new File(new URI(filePath));` but I am getting `IllegalArgumentException : URI is not absolute`. Why is so ? How do I get Absolute Path ? Is there any other alternative to pick any file using Intent & then Uri ?

In android debugger uri object shows like (It is from downloads): `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/67`

& `uri.getPath()` gives me `/document/67`

Comment: are you picking image?

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `filePath`, also why are you using `File(URI)` ctor?

Comment: Sohail Zahid I am not picking file with specified mime type, @pskink plz see edited question.

Comment: ok, what do you want to do with the returned `Uri`?

Comment: @pskink I want a File object to process the file, If you have any alternative to read file please suggest

Comment: use `ContentResolver#openInputStream(Uri)`

Comment: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` worked for me thanks pskink & Serhio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returned `Uri` may have scheme that differs from `file://`, i.e. it is not always a URI to local file or to file available to all device apps. E.g. it may be `content://` URI and its path has nothing in common with local filesystem path. Fair way to workaround it - test if scheme is `file://` and if not - open `InputStream` via `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` and then copy content to local temporary file.

Comment: In debugger I see scheme as content://

Comment: And this is the reason why you can not  use URI path as path to local file - this path is an abstract entity that has some meaning only in context of `ContentProvider`, that has generated this URI. You can just use workaround described in answer.

Comment: So your are suggesting that if scheme is content I have to do this --->"open InputStream via context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) and then copy content to local temporary file." ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.